# Статьи, видео, книги, програмы по рисованию в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Все хотел как начать осваивать canvas, думал: да что там... плоские картинки, все задается формулой, но тут недавно наткнулся на один сайт, где в плоскости расположенной в трехмерном пространстве (в перспективе) как бы плавали точки, а при прокрутке страницы, они рассыпались и собирались в спираль днк, затем в пульсирующую сферу и тд, и все это в трехмерном пространстве.

И я подумал, что либо это просто капец как сложно: описать движение более 1000 элементов, либо на это в canvas есть свои методы (свера, спираль, плоскость, и тд), а, может быть, есть специальная программа, которая позволяет сформировать эти фигуры в 3D, а потом экспортировать код.

В общем, для меня увиденное - это верх рисования в canvas, и не верится, что человек это описал ручками.

Если есть продвинутые статьи с примерами, прошу прикрепить ссылки

Comment: Библиотека построена на основе OpenGL ES 2.0 и обеспечивает API для 3D-графики[4], использует HTML5-элемент canvas, также оперирует с DOM. Автоматическое управление памятью предоставляется языком JavaScript https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Comment: Вобщем нужно будет писать код для видеокарты, шейдеры и все такое =) очень увлекательно скажу я вам

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/